# Error in Declaration of cursor

Tags: sql-server

```
set @SQL=N' select  @minTableId   = MIN(id)  from ' + @AcDB + '.dbo.vTblOfRollNo '

Declare Cursor For
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL
```

if i have declared all the variables in above query but Declaration of cursor in above 
query shows ERROR.
What is Solution?

Comment: Are you sure you want a cursor? It is bad style to use cursors if you could do the same using ordinary SQL. Have you tried writing the query without cursors? Why is that not possible in your case?

Comment: Your SQL appears to only return one value anyway - what's the point of the cursor?

Answer (score 2):

In order to execute a cursor over dynamic SQL you must put the output of your dynamic sql into a temporary table and then cursor over the temporary table like this:

```
DECLARE @TableName NVARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(1000)
CREATE TABLE #TempTABLE(email NVARCHAR(200))

SET @TableName='Users'
SELECT @SQL='INSERT INTO #TempTable SELECT email FROM ' + @TableName 
EXEC (@SQL)

DECLARE MyCursor CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM #TempTable
OPEN MyCursor
DECLARE @Email NVARCHAR(200)
FETCH NEXT FROM MyCursor INTO @Email

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
 PRINT 'Email = ' + @Email
 FETCH NEXT FROM MyCursor INTO @Email
END

CLOSE MyCursor
DEALLOCATE MyCursor
DROP TABLE #TempTABLE
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you need a cursor for this

try

```
DECLARE @AcDB VARCHAR(10),
        @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

set @SQL=N' select MIN(id)  from ' + @AcDB + '.dbo.vTblOfRollNo '

DECLARE @Temp TABLE(
        MinID INT
)
INSERT INTO @Temp EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL 

DECLARE @minTableId INT
SELECT TOP 1 @minTableId = MinID FROM @Temp

SELECT @minTableId
```

**EDIT**: Also here is the actual CURSOR documentation

[DECLARE CURSOR (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx)